# How to fix FlowJS error for dynamic Boolean variable assignments?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```
//Person Type  
type Person{
    canDisplayButton:boolean,
    anotherEmail:string
}

const canEdit:boolean = person.canDisplayButton && data.anotherEmail;
```

Flow throws an error saying `anotherEmail: string (This type is incompatible with boolean)`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: If you're trying to determine whether `data.anotherEmail` is defined, can you not use `!!data.anotherEmail` to determine truthiness of the variable?

Comment: Yes, `!!` worked. Using `Boolean()` also worked.

Comment: In that case, I've changed it to an answer - can you mark it as correct please @titogeo?

Comment: Thanks titogeo, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to determine whether `data.anotherEmail` is defined, can you not use `!!data.anotherEmail` to determine truthiness of the variable?

Comment: Or in a more explicit way, `Boolean(data.anotherEmail)`

Answer (score 1):

The error that you see is happening because

```
const canEdit = true && 'text';

// results into

canEdit // 'text'
```

As you defined that `canEdit` is boolean - assigning a string to it - results in an error. So the solution it to assign an appropriate type to it

```
const canEdit:boolean = person.canDisplayButton && data.anotherEmail !== '';

// or 

const canEdit:boolean = Boolean(person.canDisplayButton && data.anotherEmail);

// or

let canEdit = false;

if (person.canDisplayButton && data.anotherEmail) {
    canEdit = true;
}
```

Comment: could be `undefined` as well right? I also have more fields to evaluate. I am looking if there is a `flow`solution for this?